# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@LocationID". in MVC

Tags: c#, datatable

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare
>   the scalar variable "@LocationID".
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 43:  Line 44:             conn.Open(); Line 45:
>   adapter.Fill(dt); Line 46:             conn.Close(); Line 47:
>
> Source File: C:\Users\Dev D\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MySafar\MySafar\Models\DBUtility.cs    Line: 45

Location.cs (Model class)

```
public class Location
{
        public int LocationID;
        public string LocationName;
        public string PhotoPath;
        public string Details;
        public string CityID;
}        

public int Update()
{
            string query = "UPDATE Location SET LocationName = @LocationName, PhotoPath = @PhotoPath, Details = @Details, CityID = @CityID WHERE LocationID = @LocationID";
            List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LocationID", this.LocationID));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LocationName", this.LocationName));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhotoPath", this.PhotoPath));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Details", this.Details));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CityID", this.CityID));

            return DBUtility.ModifyData(query, parameters);
}

public bool SelectByPK()
{
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Location WHERE LocationID = @LocationID";
            List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LocationID", this.LocationID));

            DataTable dt = DBUtility.SelectData(query, parameters);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                this.LocationName = dt.Rows[0]["LocationName"].ToString();
                this.PhotoPath = dt.Rows[0]["PhotoPath"].ToString();
                this.Details = dt.Rows[0]["Details"].ToString();
                //this.CityID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["CityID"]);
                this.CityID = dt.Rows[0]["CityID"].ToString();

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

Methods for view in AdminController

```
public ActionResult Location_Edit()
{
            Location l = new Location();
            l.LocationID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
            l.SelectByPK();

            return View(l)
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Location_List_Edit()
{
            Location l = new Location();
            l.LocationID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
            l.LocationName = Request.Form["LocationName"];
            l.PhotoPath = Request.Form["PhotoPath"];
            l.Details = Request.Form["
            l.CityID = Request.Form["CityID"];

            l.Update();

            return View("Location_List", new DataTable());
}
```

DBUtility.cs (Model class define for database methods for modify insert and select the data)

```
public static DataTable SelectData(String query, List<SqlParameter> parameter)
{
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Dev D\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\MySafar\\MySafar\\App_Data\\MySafarDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;

            command.CommandText = query;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            conn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();

            return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have problem in this method

```
public static DataTable SelectData(String query, List<SqlParameter> parameter)
```

heere you are passing `List<SqlParameter> parameter` but not adding it to `command` parameter list.

that is the reason it giving you error. add parameter as given below, add this line of code in your method.

```
foreach( var param in  List<SqlParameter> parameter))
  command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: Like This??

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;

foreach( var param in  List<SqlParameter> parameter))
  command.Parameters.Add(param);

            command.CommandText = query;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            conn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();

            return dt;
}